# Adapter in another adapter usage

Tags: android, listview, gridview, android-listview

I have a ListView. There is a custom adapter for this ListView. I have 2 item types which are header and products. First item of listview is header, second item has a gridview (another adapter) and third item is header, forth item is gridview...etc. Everything works about ListView adapter. But the position of ListView mixes. My purpose is to get positions 1,3,5,7,9... and get items of ArrayList category by 0,1,2,3,4... I write a code such that:

```
holder.catId = 0;
if (position % 2 == 1) {
    holder.catId = this.mCategoryIds.get( (position - 1) / 2);
    Log.d("pos", "catId: " + holder.catId);
}
```

When I log, I can get first, second and third catId but after that catId not changes according to position. Is it possible to find a solution or there exists an alternative?

Comment: So, basically you want to map `1,3,5,7,9,...` to `0,1,2,3,4,...` right?

Comment: Actually, yes. After that, I'll get ArrayList items by 0,1,2,3,4...

Comment: `((position - 1) / 2)` will do that. Don't know why its not working for you. Have you tried to log that value?

Comment: Yes, I can log. When I see the values, it can log the first, second and third values of 12 as correct. But the others are not logged.

Answer (score 0):

I've sold my problem by removing ViewHolder in adapter of ListView.